# question upvotes lost

Tags: support, status-bydesign, voting

I'm pretty sure some of my recent upvotes on questions have been lost. I'm almost positive I upvoted [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11241) when it was new, and I just discovered that I had no glowing arrow and could vote again. And I've noticed that the same is true for [other recent questions in the (tag:mi-yodeya-series)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series?sort=newest&pagesize=20). (It may well be true for other questions also, but I don't necessarily remember which of those I've previously upvoted and which I haven't, whereas I'm pretty sure I've upvoted all recent mi-yodeya-series questions that I've answered, and there are quite a few such questions that I've discovered my vote discounted on.)

*edit:* I've discovered another: [11007](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11007). it's not in the mi-yodeya-series, I commented "+1", it looks the kind of question I would have upvoted, and it's not marked with my upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently noticed that the [user](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses) who posted all of the questions you refer to happened to have lost a whole bunch of rep points overnight. I suspect that some automatic [vote fraud detection](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) process tripped based on you upvoting some high number or percentage of that user's posts, or something like that, and invalidated your votes for that user's posts.

Comment: I once had a similar thing. After I posted an answer to someone's question (a relatively new user), I found that someone had gone through all of my posted questions and upvoted them. (I assumed that the questioner was just so grateful that merely upvoting and accepting the answer was not enough for him.) After about an hour (give or take), the votes and points disappeared.

Comment: A **mod** is suspected for vote  fraud?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, you spelled that correctly, with an 'm' and not a 'g'.

Comment: Tagging the question [meta-tag:status-bydesign] in light of this (seemingly correct) answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happen to me as well. Since I usually read the whole page and then go back and cast the votes before moving on to the next page, I just assumed that I exited the page before the vote could be saved.

Comment: This was my first thought as well, and I have noticed it happening especially when accessing the site from my mobile device.